# How to use UnSafeRawPointer in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, camera, swift3

I am working on camera with location.
What i am doing is when the Capture Image button is clicked, I gather all the location information in a dictionary and further Set it in CFDictionarySetValue. Here is the problem I am facing.
The format of `CFDictionarySetValue` is `dict, key, value` as follows:

```
CFDictionarySetValue((dictionary)CFMutableDictionary!, (key)UnsafeRawPointer!,(value) UnsafeRawPointer!)
```

and my dictionary , key and value are as follows:

**dictionary:**

```
let mutable : CFMutableDictionary = CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy(nil, 0, metaDict)
```

**key:**

```
kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary
```

**value**

```
let gpsDict : NSDictionary = [kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude: Int(fabs(loc.coordinate.latitude)), kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitudeRef : ((loc.coordinate.latitude >= 0) ? "N" : "S"), kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude : Int(fabs(loc.coordinate.longitude)),kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitudeRef : ((loc.coordinate.longitude >= 0) ? "E" : "W") , kCGImagePropertyGPSTimeStamp  : formatter.string(from: loc.timestamp), kCGImagePropertyGPSAltitude  : Int(fabs(loc.altitude))]
```

It looks like `CFDictionarySetValue(mutable, kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary, gpsDictionary)`

And I get error on above line saying: `"Cannot convert value of type NSDictionary to UnSafeRawPointer! for gpsDictionary"`

Tried some ways but still no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing an `NSDictionary` as an argument to `CFDictionarySetValue(...)`, but the expected type is a pointer of type `UnSafeRawPointer`. The same is true for the second argument `kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary`. You are passing a `NSString` instead of a pointer.

To fix this, create pointers for both parameters. One possible approach:

```
let pGPSDictionary = Unmanaged.passUnretained(kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary).toOpaque()
let pGpsDict = Unmanaged.passUnretained(gpsDict).toOpaque()
CFDictionarySetValue(mutable, pGPSDictionary, pGpsDict)
```

There is a nicer syntax to create `UnSafeRawPointer`s, which I can not remember right now.